# Boot from external hard drive and access internal hard drive?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, external-hdd

Suppose Ubuntu are installed on both of my internal and external hard drives, although their versions are different.

How can I boot the Ubuntu on the external hard drive connected to my laptop by usb?

After that, how can I access the internal hard drive under the Ubuntu on the external hard drive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To boot your external hard drive, you can set it as first hard drive in BIOS, or try hitting F12, (or similar), when booting, to get an option to boot it.
Once it is running you can access the internal drive using Files, (the file manager like app).